# Light Filters for Glasses

Tags: optics, light-pollution

I am curious whether someone here has knowledge in the light filtering area.

Described in laywoman's terms, this is what I am curious whether it's possible (and how):

- Filter out clear daylight and its reflections off bright colored walls
- Let the artificial light pass, but only to a certain luminosity threshold

Answer (score 1):

For any source of light to be visible to the eye, it must be within a certain range of wavelengths. This means that artificial light sources will share wavelengths with natural ones, and a filter has no way of telling the difference between them. This means it is probably not possible to perform the filtering trick you are asking about.

Comment: (rephrased) Okay, let's go from there. Would it be possible to let a certain light emitting area be visible but dampen rest of the light sources?

Comment: I do not know! -nn

Comment: A pair of glasses with the lens covered except for a small hole...

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

1. You are asking about clear daylight. Contrary to popular belief, Sunlight is white light (not yellow), and this means that Sunlight is made up of photons of all visible wavelengths.
   It is the combination of all these visible wavelengths that our eyes receptors sense as white (yellow because of the scattering of the atmosphere).
   Now if you use an artificial light, that is made up of photons that are missing some visible wavelengths, then you might be able to build a filter that only lets through the specific wavelength artificial light, and reflects white light (most of it, certain wavelengths you do not want) from the Sun.
2. You are talking about Sunlight, and it is a natural light that has a certain polarization (Rayleigh scattering). If you could build a filter that only lets through certain polarized artificial light, and reflects natural Sunlight, then you would be able to do it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_sky_model